# Error importing PSTs into Exchange 2010 SP1

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, import

I created a PST at the location `c:\pstfiles\user.pst` to test importing PSTs into Exchange 2010 via PowerShell.

I'd already installed 64bit outlook on the server, and added import export roles to the account I was using.

I was then using the command

```
Import-Mailbox –Identity [Username] –PSTFolderPath c:\pstfiles\user.pst
```

to import this pst file into [username]'s mailbox.

And get the following error:

```
Error was found for XXX because: Error occurred in the step: Approving object. An unknown error
has occurred., error code: -2147221219
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [Import-Mailbox], RecipientTaskException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CFFD629B,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.ImportMailbox
```

I'm struggling to find information on what this means.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `Exchange Trusted Subsystem` read/write access to the folder that contains the PST.  Try again after adding this to your ACL on the pstfiles folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running fixmapi at the command prompt. That's fixed this error in the past.

Also, Exchange 2010 SP1 is still in Beta. It is possible this is a bug as SP1 isn't ready for production yet.
**EDIT**

Since that didn't work, try this:

> get-mailbox | Add-mailboxpermission -User Administrator -AccessRights FullAccess

Looks like it might be a permissions issue
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/886a6c39-b975-408a-827c-fb3c07ea579b

Also try running powershell as administrator

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason, I have tried this today but I still get the same message. I have read some articles on importing PSTs into 2010, hence getting as far as I have got, but I’m lost now. Has anyone here succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing -identity [username] to -identity [display name / email address / exchange alias]

**Edit**
Just noticed there is a ' at the end of your command is this a typo or was it intentional?

Comment: So I had to postpone the project but I am now back on it with the help of the following website: http://sysadmin-talk.org/2010/08/how-to-import-pst-files-into-exchange-2010-the-manual-way/

Even with this information it's still a bit of a pig. It would be great to hear if anyone else is having problems/ has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The Error caused in the command is due to the file path provided. The file path "c:\pstfiles\user.pst" is the normal path. But for Exchange processing, the path provided is the **UNC Shared File Path**.

This File path is found in the **Properties** >> **Sharing** section of the Folder containing the PST file.

The **UNC File path** would be like "**\Exchange_version\pstfiles\user.pst**"

Also, provide full control to the folder regarding permissions on Read and Write. Provide this permission by going to **Folder Properties**>> **Security**.
Under **Permission** section, provide **Full control** to read and write permissions.

Hope that this will resolve your issue.

Adwin John