# Need help on importing PSTs into Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

I would really like to hear if anyone has (and how you did it) successfully imported PSTs into Exchange 2010 (RTM or SP1).

I have tried via PowerShell (for SP1) but I am now stuck.

Link to my earlier question: [Error importing PSTs into Exchange 2010 SP1](https://serverfault.com/questions/169404/error-importing-psts-into-exchange-2010-sp1)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't duplicate your question just because your other one didn't get much attention.  Update your other question, if you've tried other things, but don't duplicate it.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for the tip - I am new here so just getting used to things!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error importing PSTs into Exchange 2010 SP1](http://serverfault.com/questions/169404/error-importing-psts-into-exchange-2010-sp1)

Answer (score 0):

We did a migration from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 using the EMC. (*FYI - the mailbox will be offline during migration if you're running Ex 2010 Std.*) Basically:
1. Go to the **EMC** > **Recipient Configuration** > **Mailbox**
2. Right-Click the mailbox you want to move and choose "**New Local Move Request**" (*Ex 2003 mailboxes show as Legacy Mailbox*)
3. Complete the Move Request Wizard and look for the green "tick" to show it completed successfully

Here is export/import exmaple on per PST basis:
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

To Import PST file to Exchange 2010, you need to perform the following steps:

1.Open Exchange Management Shell to use PowerShell Command.

2.To assign Role Permission use below command

- For the individual:

**New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role "Mailbox Import Export" –User Administrator**

- For Security Group:

**New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role "Mailbox Import Export" -SecurityGroup MailboxExportImportGroup**

3. Execute following command to import PST mailbox to Exchange Server

**New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox “User_Mailbox_Name” -FilePath “UNC_shared_File_Path”**

**Note**: UNC shared File Path is different from the Normal File Path. If you don't know how to create UNC shared File Path, Refer: **[Creating UNC shared file path for a PST file](https://www.edbtopstoutlook.com/blog/2010/import-pst-to-mailbox-via-powershell.html)**

4.Verify Status of import process through the following command

**Get-MailboxImportRequest**

Now Open Exchange Account to view the imported mailbox file data.

If you still leads to trouble, you can go to the [**Link**](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/exchange-import.html) which will import all the PST files to the Exchange mailboxes in a single instance.

Hope that this will resolve your issue,

Robinsan